# Orientation problem

Tags: objective-c, ipad, orientation

i have created and ipad application.
i started off with window based application and added 2 view controllers(loginviewcontroller , detailviewcontroler ) . both have their own XIB'S. the added the loginviewcontroller object in in the appdelegate applicationdidfinishlaunch method ,  i wrote code to move back and forth between 2 views. Here is the code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Login *mylogin = [[Loginviewcontroller alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:mylogin.view];
    //detailview *tv=[[detailviewcontroller alloc] init];
    //  [window addSubview:tv.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

The problem is that the willrotatetointerfaceorientation method runs only from the loginviewcontroller class even if i am in the detailviewcontroller.

if i add the tickets view to the appdelegate then it runs the willrotatetointerfaceorientation method from detailviewcontroller  ,  so in summary it runs the willrotatetointerfaceorientation method from only the object  which was added to appdelegate.

how do i make the 2 view controllers run their respective willrotatetointerfaceorientation methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIViewController has the method

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

override this method in your both viewcontroller classes(i.e. (loginviewcontroller , detailviewcontroler )

write this code

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    //write your code which you want to during rotation

return Yes;

}

Answer (score 0):

The rotation messages are being sent only to the controller of topmost view. You should forward them manually in appropriate methods.